# SetInterval - dificultades

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Necesito anular un setInterval que se dispara cuando se clicea un botón. La función se encuentra en un módulo y se exporta al index.
Muestro la función:

```
let d = document;
export default function digitalWatch(watch, showWatchBtn, hideWatchBtn, hours, minutes, seconds ) {
    
    d.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.matches(showWatchBtn)) {
            
            setInterval(()=>{
                document.querySelector(watch).classList.add('is-active');
                currentTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
                d.querySelector(showWatchBtn).disabled = true
            }, 1000)
        }
        if(e.target.matches(hideWatchBtn)){
            
            d.querySelector(watch).classList.remove('is-active');
            clearInterval();
        }
    })
}
```

El clearInterval() que está en el segundo if se debería disparar cuando se clicea un segundo botón. Pero no lo hace. La línea de código que está encima si funciona, pero al segundo sigue funcionando el setInterval del primer condicional. Cómo logro desactivarlo?

Comment: te falta la referencia, ["If the parameter provided does not identify a previously established action, this method does nothing."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) proba algo asi `d.elinterval=setinterval( ... )` y luego `clearInterval(d.elInterval)` ( d o this o el scope donde corre el set/clear interval )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que falta en tú código es asignar el valor de setInterval a una variable, para poder llamarlo desde otro fragmento, como lo muestro a continuación:

```js
let d = document;
let reloj;
export default function digitalWatch(watch, showWatchBtn, hideWatchBtn, hours, minutes, seconds ) {
    
    d.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.matches(showWatchBtn)) {
            
            reloj = setInterval(()=>{
                document.querySelector(watch).classList.add('is-active');
                currentTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
                d.querySelector(showWatchBtn).disabled = true
            }, 1000)
        }
        if(e.target.matches(hideWatchBtn)){
            
            d.querySelector(watch).classList.remove('is-active');
            clearInterval(reloj);
        }
    })
}
```